# How to speed up dd-wrt iptables command execution

Tags: iptables, router, dd-wrt

I have a custom firewall script in dd-wrt router. It has thousands of lines in a user-chain like this:

```
/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A XXXX -d 1.2.32.0/19 -j RETURN
/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A XXXX -d 1.2.64.0/18 -j RETURN
/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A XXXX -d 1.3.0.0/16 -j RETURN
```

Each time the router start, this script will run serval minutes, and when PPPOE re-dail, configuration change, this script will run again. This too boring for me.

Is there any way to make this script faster, is a batch mode exist in dd-wrt?

Thanks.

Comment: Thousands? Are you sure all those destinations cannot be aggregated into a few larger ones?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iptables-save` to dump a full configuration and `iptables-restore` to load it later. Note that loading will *overwrite* any existing rules; if you need to merge, then you'll have to generate the rules file by a script.

Alternatively, replace `-d` with an ipset match (`-m set --match-set dontnat dst`); the ipset can also be loaded in batch using `ipset restore`. I don't know whether DD-WRT supports ipsets, though.